# Javascript function can write to console but not returning value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function in javascript which can write the output to the console but it is unable to return the value..

```
fetchData: function(dateToFetch){
            if (mP.viewMode == 1){
                $.each(mealData.DailymPs, function(k, item){
                    if( item.Date == formatDate(mP.chosenDate) ){
                        mP.DayPlan.mPDayData = item;
                        return mP.populateMealDayPlan();
                    }       
                })
            } else if (mP.viewMode == 2){
            //  debugger;
                $.each(mealData.DailymPs, function(k, item){
                    if( item.Date == (dateToFetch) ){
                        mP.DayPlan.mPDayData = item;
                        console.log(mP.populateMealDayPlan());
                        var returnObj = mP.populateMealDayPlan();
                        return returnObj;
                    }       
                })
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to fix it by changing it from:

```
...
$.each(mealData.DailymPs, function(k, item){
    if( item.Date == (dateToFetch) ){
        mP.DayPlan.mPDayData = item;
        console.log(mP.populateMealDayPlan());
        var returnObj = mP.populateMealDayPlan();
        return returnObj;
    }       
})
...
```

to

```
...
var returnObj = null;
$.each(mealData.DailymPs, function(k, item){
    if( item.Date == (dateToFetch) ){
        mP.DayPlan.mPDayData = item;
        console.log(mP.populateMealDayPlan());
        returnObj = mP.populateMealDayPlan();
        return false; // break out of each()
    }       
})
if(returnObj != null) return returnObj;
...
```

**Note**: You'll also need to externalize the return variable in the `if` condition. I've demonstrated how that can be done for the else condition.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return something from a `$.each` loop, assign it to a variable in the outer scope, `return false;` to break the loop and then return it after the `$.each();` call.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing mP.populateMealDayPlan, my first guess would be that calling the function twice to get the values changes some internal values of mP. In other words if I am right and you comment out the console.log, there should be a return value. You could also do:

```
var returnObj = mP.populateMealDayPlan();    
console.log(returnObj);
```

rather than calling mP.populateMealDayPlan in the console.log

If this is not the case then I think we would need more context in order to help.

Answer (score 0):

Your return statement returns from the function passed to the `each` method, not from your `fetchData` function. The [grep function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) will be useful here:

```
fetchData: function(dateToFetch) {
  var selector = mP.viewMode == 1 ? function(item) { return item.Date == formatDate(mP.chosenDate) } : function (item) { return item.Date == dateToFetch};

  var matched = $.grep(mealData.DailymPs, selector);
  if (matched.length) {
    var item = matched[0];
    mP.DayPlan.mPDayData = item;
    console.log(mP.populateMealDayPlan());
    return mP.populateMealDayPlan();
  }
}
```